# how to create a virtual storage in esxi 6.5 from 2 physical HDDs?

Tags: vmware, esxi

I have a new server with 2*1TB HDDs and I have Esxi 6.5 installed on it. how can I create a Microsoft Windows VM on It with 2TB as C drive on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll have to use the in-guest Windows disk manager to make that happen... and even then, I'd not recommend it.

For testing purposes, you can create 1 - 1TB VM Hard Disk on the first HDD then another 1TB VM Hard Disk on the second drive. Then, within the guest OS combine the two drives together. That process is laid out in the following [article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-one-large-volume-using-multiple-hard-drives-windows-10)